# asp.net Chart control not loading most of the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

My site is hosted in a shared enviroment (arvixe), most of time the charts won't load, it will look like a broken image link (I tried on chrome, IE and Firefox). If I reload the page it might help but not always. I should specify that on my local enviroment it does not occur at all

my config are as follows:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="Storage=session;Timeout=20;"/>
  </appSettings>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,     Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

And my chart control:

```
<asp:chart id="Chart1" ViewStateMode="Enabled" runat="server" Height="296px" Width="600px" ImageStorageMode="UseHttpHandler" Palette="BrightPastel" imagetype="Png" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White">
```

I also tried using file instead of session in the config, the files are being written to the folder but still the same problem, I am confused because sometimes it works and the charts loads fine and sometimes (most of the time) it does not.

Comment: Any error info logged at the server somewhere? Maybe use Fiddler to see if server is returning any error information in the response. Without it, we'd be only guessing: from server setup, over to coding mistakes, to your glasses (just kidding). But, you get the point. :)

Comment: Can you post complete declaration of `asp:Chart`? Can you try with `<asp:chart id="Chart1" runat="server" Height="296px" Width="600px"` don't put rest like `ImageStorageMode` etc, which you have put in sample code.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because it's on a web farm.  This link explains what is happening and has some things to try:

http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1054

Note:  The Microsoft chart control was originally the Dundas chart.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in code behind:

```
Chart1.ImageStorageMode = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;
```